# Why Do I Need A setTimout To Make My Knockout Bound UI Update All The Time?

Tags: knockout.js

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div class="po-detail-row-one-item">
        <label style="display: block;">Vendor Agreement:<span class="required">*</span> <span data-bind="visible: isVendorAgreeChangeLinkVisible">(<a href="#" data-bind="click: enableVendorAgreeChange">Change</a>)</span></label>

        <div style="display: none;" data-bind="visible: isVendorAgreeSelectVisible">
            <select data-bind="options: $parent.vendorAgreements, optionsText: 'vendorAgreementName', value: selectedVendorAgreement, optionsCaption: '-- Please Select --', enable: $parent.canEditVendorAgreement, hasFocus: isVendorAgreeFocus"></select>
        </div>

        <div style="display: none;" data-bind="hidden: isVendorAgreeSelectVisible">
            <span class="po-detail-row-one-item-label" data-bind="text: vendorAgreementName"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When a new item is loaded from the server using AJAX, I get the appropriate items for the `select` list and set the selected value:

```
    // Load the Vendor Agreements and set the selected Vendor Agreement
    self.vendorAgreements([]);
    getVendorAgreementsSelectList(po.product.vendorID, po.regionID, function () {
        var vendorAgreements = self.vendorAgreements();
        for (var i = 0, max = vendorAgreements.length; i < max; i++) {
            var va = vendorAgreements[i];
            if (va.vendorAgreementID === po.vendorAgreementID) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    loadedPO.selectedVendorAgreement(va);
                }, 100);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the last of 3 `select` lists that are cascading. The function passed to the `getVendorAgreementsSelectList` function executes after the observable array has been updated with data from the server. See that 100 ms `setTimeout`? If I don't have that in there and just call `loadedPO.selectedVendorAgreement(va);`, only 60 to 70 percent of the time will my `select` list get it's value set. Why do I need that `setTimeout`? Why does this happen and how can I get my UI to always update without it?

Comment: Is the 100 important? Does it work just as well if it's 0?

Comment: @RoyJ 100 was the lowest value I found where the UI would update consistently on my workstation. Zero did not work consistently.

Comment: Is `loadedPO` definitely not changing during this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information here to say specifically what's going on. In general, the need for a `setTimeout` is caused by race conditions: multiple asynchronous events are being processed, and their order of execution is arbitrary. The `setTimeout` allows them to finish up so that the system state is stable.

My best guess is that something else is setting `loadedPO.selectedVendorAgreement`'s contents back to its former value after you set it to its new one here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you are spot on about the multiple asynchronous events, there are 4 or 5 AJAX calls that are made in this function. I need a good pattern for chaining my callbacks.